# Stick footer at the end of the content

Tags: html, css, footer

I have the same code for my footer in all sub pages. In this particular one, I have a map. The footer is located at the bottom of all pages except this one. 
I noticed that of I zoom out in my browser, it will go to the bottom. Otherwise, it is located on the map.
I already tested the answer here [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page) but it just changed the position of footer and it is still in the middle of the map.

```
    <style>

    .footer {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 60px;
        }   
                #map {

             height: 250px;
             width: 30%;

            }
         </style>

</head>
<body>

        <nav class="topnav">
                <a  href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a  href="resume.html">Resume</a>
                <a   href="awards.html">Awards</a>
                <a   href="teaching.html">Teaching</a>
                <a  class="active" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>



           <br>
            <h3>Address</h3>
    <p>1750 cyg Hwy </p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat:33333, lng: -33333};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyALqA8E2Iu2s_fRkVcsUG__-3333fQEOCE &callback=initMap">
    </script>
<footer class="footer">
              ©copyright    </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Xufox My mistake! I correct it. Anyway, the result is not different.

Comment: @Xufox It is correct in my original code and I correct it here. I think the problem is the map. I just have one error in validation: 'Bad value https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyALqA8E2Iu2s_fRkVcsUG__-lKf3fQEOCE&callback=initMap for attribute src on element script: Illegal character in query: space is not allowed.'